# On-Scroll animate script. It runs only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want this script run whenever the user scrolls the second div. Second div in the sense the "content" div. First div is header. On-Scroll animate script.

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.content').scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100)
        {
            $(".header").animate({"height": "300px"},"slow");
        }
        else
        {
            $(".header").animate({"height": "100px"},"fast");
        }
    });
});
</script>
<style>
body{
margin:auto;
overflow:hidden;
background-color:#000;
}
.outer{
width:800px;
border:thin solid;
height:900px;
background-color:#fff;
margin:auto;
}
.wrapper{
width:800px;
position:relative;
z-index:100;
height:900px;
}
.header{
width:800px;
height:300px;
border: thin solid #F00;
background-color:#666;
}
.content{
width:800px;
height:600px;
overflow:scroll;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="outer">
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="content"> 
<p>Dummy content so that the content makes the div to scroll.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Script must run whenever the user scroll the div.

Comment: Can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) please?

Comment: or the html to go with the above

Comment: Hi Pete I have added the html and css codes. Thanks for ur response.

Comment: Hi Mister J, I've added jsfiddle but i dont know how to link it here. Thanks for your response. Please check this link http://jsfiddle.net/yU5VC/1/

Comment: Do you agree what you said was working is not in your jsfiddle?
I understood, you forgot to add jQuery. Here is an updated version http://jsfiddle.net/yU5VC/2/

Comment: What do you want it to do exactly? I think you also have some logic issues. You want the header to minify when the user has scrolled content, and to go back to original size when he is near the beginning of the content div?

Comment: Hello MisterJ, Thanks for your solution. As u said, it's extremely slow in firefox - which leaded me to think it's not working. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working on Google Chrome : http://jsfiddle.net/3kySD/2/
I don't know why but on my FireFox (v22.0) it is working but extremely slow.
I have changed only a little thing in your code which leads you to think it wasn't working in my opinion... You had this test :

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100)
```

I replaced it with this one, so the header bar will be biggest when the content div is at the top, and will be smaller when you are reading the content div:

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() < 100)
```

Comment: Hello MisterJ, Thanks for your solution. As u said, it's extremely slow in firefox - which leaded me to think it's not working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you think it close your request, you should click on the checkbox at the left of my answer. Else be free to tell what you want, but a new question may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Add .stop()

```
$(".header").stop().animate({"height": "300px"},"slow");
```

Comment: Hi Sbml, I want the script to run whenever the user scroll the content div. Thanks for ur response. After I added .stop() it prevented the script running from once.